# Infer Generic Type from Concrete Type

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-generics

I'm trying to implement a function `map` that takes a function of type `Mapper` (`a -> b`) and a functor `f a`, and returns a functor `f b`. I have trouble getting TypeScript to correctly infer the return type of `map`.

I define a functor as any object that has a `map` method:

```
type Mapper<a, b> = (arg: a) => b;

interface Functor<a> {
  // I have Functor<b> as the return type
  // but I'd need something like (generictypeof Functor<a>)<b>
  // which I don't know how to do
  map<b>(func: Mapper<a, b>): Functor<b>; 
}
```

Now I can define my `map` function:

```
function map<a, b>(func: Mapper<a, b>, functor: Functor<a>) {
  return functor.map(func);
}
```

And use it like so:

```
const result = map(
  (a: number) => a + 1,
  [1, 2, 3],
);
```

This compiles just fine; however, TypeScript tells me that `result` is of type `Functor<number>`. While I understand why it arrives at that conclusion, how would I need to change my code so that TypeScript can infer that `result` is of type `Array<number>`?

Any approach I tried so far would require me to extend a Generic type without making it into a concrete type first, or inferring a Generic type from a concrete type (see my comment above), which I can't figure out how to do in TypeScript.

Comment: @Lesiak yes, thanks!